# How to increase the speed of MySQL query with extra condition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, query-performance

I'm trying to speed up the following query as it takes quite long to run: now it's 'only' about 1.5 seconds, but it will certainly get slower with more rows (which will 10x over the next period).

Basically, I want to show all the rows from the orders table for the user, and per row show the total order amount (which is the SUM of the orders_products table).

```
SELECT 
orders.order_number,
orders.order_date, 
companies.company_name,
COALESCE(SUM(orders_products.product_price * orders_products.product_quantity),0) AS order_value 
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = orders.company_id
LEFT JOIN orders_products ON orders_products.order_id = orders.id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = orders.user_id 
WHERE orders.user_id = '$user_id'
AND companies.user_id = '$user_id'
GROUP BY orders.id ORDER BY orders.order_date DESC, orders.order_number DESC
```

I've tried adding another condition `AND orders_products.user_id = '$user_id'`. Speed wise the query was about 12x faster (yeah!) but the problem is that not all orders have products in them. In this case, the orders without products in them are not returned.

How do I change my query so that despite of an order not having products in them, it still is returned (with total order value 0), whilst also speeding up the query?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Just to verify: You have set the correct indexes? I assume you have.

Comment: I haven't set any indexes. I have heared about them, but don't have a clue on how to set them... Would that help to speed up queries like these?

Comment: Yes, indexes are THE WAY to speed things up.

Comment: Unrelated, but there are some things that I find strange. What do you join the *users* table for? Why are you trying to *outer join* the companies table? Why does a company have a *user ID*?

Comment: @Thorsten, I join the users table because I also need to select some details for the user. I now see that I left that select statement out of my code. My apologies for the confusion. I'm outer joining the companies table because I want to get all the orders, and join the companies to show the company name in the order row. Should I use another join? The names users / user_id might be a bit confusing, but in short: I have users, and these users can add companies. And in turn, these companies can add orders. So I want to know which user added which company.

Comment: You would outer join companies to orders, if you wanted to see orders that are not related to companies. I don't think these even exist, so what you probably want is an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: As to the user IDs: Every table has its own user_id. So, a company can be added as you say by user A, this company places an order associated with user B and this order contains positions assigned to user C. That is many users involved and there are maybe even more (a product table with a user_id column ? ;-) This may be desired or it may be a flaw in the data model.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. I will use ```INNER JOIN``` then. As for the user IDs: no, the company added by user A can't place an order associated with user B. I feel it's kind of hard to explain why I have users without going into depth, and as the issue is solved by using the indexes, I believe it's ok like this. Also, the user_id part didn't influence the query at all. Thank you for the feedback though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it faster to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT o.order_number, o.order_date,  c.company_name,
      (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(op.product_price * op.product_quantity), 0)
       FROM orders_products op
       WHERE op.order_id = o.id
      ) AS order_value 
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
     companies c
     ON c.id = o.company_id AND c.user_id = o.user_id
WHERE o.user_id = '$user_id'
ORDER BY o.order_date DESC, o.order_number DESC
```

This gets rid of the outer aggregation which is often a performance win.

Then for performance you want the following indexes:

- `orders(user_id, order_date desc, order_number_desc, company_id)`
- `companies(id, company_id, company_name)`
- `orders_products(order_id, product_price, product_quantity)`

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, thank you for your answer. I tested the correlated subquery, but unfortunately it doesn't speed up the query.

Old query: 1.1285 seconds
New query: 1.0912 seconds

In comparison to the other query with the extra AND clause: 0.0368 seconds

Any way add the extra AND clause but still return all the orders rows even if the order has no products in them?

Comment: @Nicholas . . . You would add the condition in the `ON` clause or subquery.  I added indexes which should improve the performance.  Of course, if a single user has tens of thousands of orders, the query will take time.

Comment: I've added the condition on the subquery as follows: ```(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ROUND(orders_products.product_price, 2) * orders_products.product_quantity), 0) FROM orders_products WHERE orders_products.order_id = orders.id AND orders_products.user_id = '$user_id') AS order_value```. The query runs, but it isn't faster (1.4106 seconds). Maybe it just can't be speeded up this way, only by indexes?

Comment: @Nicholas . . . Have you tried the recommended indexes?

Comment: I posted my reply just before I saw your updated answer. I've now added the indexes and they work like a charm: 0.0273 seconds! Thank you very much for your help!